# Is it possible to use a linker script with Apple ld64 linker?

Tags: ios, macos, linker, linker-scripts

As in the title, can you use a linker script with Apple ld64 linker? I mean an option similar to -T of GNU ld.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is a feature of the GNU linker and other ELF-centric linkers; Apple's linker handles Mach-O exclusively, which has quite different semantics from ELF.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit on the semantic difference between ELF and Mach-O? Is there some particular feature of Mach-O that makes linker script senseless? Thank you